# Adding a UIView before sleeping

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `UIView *loadingView` that simply has a black BG and a `UIActivityIndicator`. I want to add this to my view, and then sleep the thread for a couple seconds:

```
[self.window addSubview:loadingView];
loadingView.hidden=NO;
sleep(2);
```

Apparently, this isn't enough time to add the view-the thread sleeps but the view isn't added, and only appears after the 2 seconds. So I tried something like this:

```
-(void)sleep
{
    sleep(2);
}

[self.window addSubview:loadingView];
loadingView.hidden=NO;
[self performSelector:@selector(sleep) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
```

This displays the view before the sleep, which is the desired result. However, under these 3 lines there are several lines of code that I don't want executed until after the sleep, and within the 0.01 seconds, all those lines are executed.

Comment: why not putting the line below to a someFunction and using `[self performSelector:@selector(someFunction) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];` and remove the sleep function.

Comment: Why do you want to impose a 3 second period of the app being unresponsive and doing nothing?

Comment: I'm doing some loading in another thread, so I don't want the lines of code below the sleep(2) to be called till after the 2 seconds..

Comment: I've added my own answer. Can you guys see if it's safe?

Comment: The right way: don't assume that your loading takes 2 seconds. (That may be the case now, but it might not be the case in the future.) When your loading is done, in its thread, do a `performSelectorOnMainThread:` to run some code in the main thread -- whatever you want to happen after loading is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why on earth are you sleeping the main thread for 2 seconds? Normally that's a horrible idea, because your app will become completely unresponsive for 2 seconds.

You have the right idea in using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. But there is no way to get around the fact: if you want something to happen after that delay, then it has to go in the method called after the delay. Just move those other lines of code after the `sleep()`.

(And really, if you want something to happen after two seconds, just use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a delay of two seconds.)

Answer (score -1):

I ended up just doing this:

```
-(void)addLoadingView
{
    [self.window addSubview:loadingView];
    loadingView.hidden=NO;
}
 //some function...
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(addLoadingView) withObject:nil];
 sleep(2);
```

I'm new to threading, so is what I'm doing here safe?